# Pygame Button getRect Collidepoint not working?

Tags: python, button, menu, pygame

I have finished the main code for my game and I have started on making a menu screen. I can display the buttons on the screen just fine but when I click somewhere I get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjmi.png):

How can I go about fixing this? If I didn't make anything clear in this question please tell me so I can clarify. Thanks!

Here is my code for the menuscreen:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()

#colours
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)
blue = (50,50,155)


display_width = 800  
display_height = 600 

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('Numeracy Ninjas')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Fonts

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 75)

#Sprites

img_button_start = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Buttons/button_start.png')
img_button_options = pygame.image.load('Sprites/Buttons/button_options.png')

gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()


class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, buttonX, buttonY):
        super().__init__()

        gameDisplay.blit(image, (buttonX, buttonY))

        pygame.display.update()

        selfrect = image.get_rect()

    def wasClicked(event):
        if selfrect.collidepoint(event.pos):
             return True

def gameIntro():
    buttons = pygame.sprite.Group()
    button_start = Button(img_button_start, 27, 0)
    button_options = Button(img_button_options, 27, 500)
    buttons.add(button_start)
    buttons.add(button_options)

    print(buttons)


    #main game loop
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print(event.pos)
                #check for every button whether it was clicked
                for btn in buttons:
                    print('forbtninbuttons')
                    if btn.wasClicked():
                        print('clicked!')

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
```

Comment: In the future, make sure to write the error in the question instead of linking to an image of the error. Linking to images reduces search-ability and makes it impossible for people with screen readers to hear the error. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 3):

You haven't declared any attributes for you class, just local variables. Try doing `self.selfrect = image.get_rect()` in your initializer and in your `wasClicked(event)` method do:

```
def wasClicked(self, event):
    if self.selfrect.collidepoint(event.pos):
         return True
```

It's usually convention to name your rect variable just *rect* though.

```
class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, buttonX, buttonY):
        super().__init__()
        #  This code doesn't make sense here. It should be inside your game loop.
        #  gameDisplay.blit(image, (buttonX, buttonY))
        #  pygame.display.update()

        self.image = image  # It's usually good to have a reference to your image.
        self.rect = image.get_rect()

    def wasClicked(self, event):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
             return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still get basically the same error though, only this time it says "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" instead of "NameError: name 'selfrect' is not defined"

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to put *self* in the method parameter. Now it should work :)

Comment: I put "self" in the method parameter, but now I get this error: "TypeError: wasClicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: Do you have `wasClicked(self, event)` method inside the Button class? And in the event-loop, do you pass the *event* variable in the parameter?

Comment: There, this should work: http://hastebin.com/xekureruki.py. I renamed some variables so they followed the naming conventions (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) and removed unnecessary code.

Comment: Thanks so much! :D